# Wordpress Woocommerce product search only working when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, archive

I have a WordPress site that has woocommerce and WPML plugins. I have different product pages for different languages. Product pages have search and when clicked search button it shows the products. In Finnish (main language) the search works fine but in english the search works only when logged in? Can anyone help?

Comment: You will need to post some code - ideally where you think the problem is.

Comment: You should contact WPML support (as the problem here is related to translations/localisation).